# Drawing over an ImageView

Tags: java, android, canvas, bitmap

I'm trying to draw over an image, which i'll save later with the drawings. My xml only have the ImageView and I tried to overwrite onDraw. It only made de Canvas works, but with no image.

```
public class Body1 extends View {

    public LayoutParams params;
    private Path path = new Path();
    private Paint brush = new Paint();


    public Body1(Context context) {
        super(context);

        brush.setAntiAlias(true);
        brush.setColor(Color.MAGENTA);
        brush.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        brush.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        brush.setStrokeWidth(8f);

        params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        float pointX = event.getX();
        float pointY = event.getY();

        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                path.moveTo(pointX, pointY);
                return true;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                path.lineTo(pointX, pointY);
                break;
            default:
                return false;
        }
        postInvalidate();
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawPath(path, brush);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK you are on the right path.
What you are missing is invalidate calls that will result in the OS calling the OnDraw of the view.

Call invalidate every time you want to update the view. But notice that your class has only a single path object and so will only draw the last segment.

If I'm not mistaken you should hold an `ArrayList` of `Path` objects.
In `onDraw` you should loop over them and draw them all one after the other.